# When I decrease the height of browser the width of box should decrease automatically

Tags: browser, height, width

When I decrease the height of browser the width of box should decrease automatically.

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Udwq.jpg)

What is the jQuery or Javascript code for this kind of requirement? Is there any `onresize="myFunction()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the box in percentage. So if you lower the height of the browser it decreases automaticly.

Simply set the parameter in your css.

`height="100%"`

`width="auto"`

Comment: I think it is not possible with css. check the image you will understand

Comment: Or just set the margin and the padding also in percentage

Comment: Here is a little Tutorial how to do it: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp